# Token Cache with Timer-Triggered Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, access-token

I am working on a timer-triggered Azure Functions and it runs every hour. The function retrieves Token using ADAL. I want to know, is it possible to do TokenCache with Timer-Triggered Azure Functions. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean `do TokenCache`?

Comment: Hi Joy, This is what I am referring to --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/token-cache or also, save the token to table storage, extend it and reuse it.

Comment: Table is durable storage and does not contain TTL (time to live) property for records, but token has an expiration date. It could be better to use a service like Redis and use the token expiration date as TTL for the stored record. BTW, your link contains all necessary info for implementation.

Comment: Do you have some code examples for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function uses client credentials to authenticate, there is no point in making a custom token cache.
Your credentials can get a new token anytime a new one is needed. 
If your function runs more often than once an hour, it can be good to use an in-memory cache to keep the current access token.

If you use refresh token, then it's another story. 
In that case you would definitely need a persistent token cache, e.g. in table storage.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to use AzureTokenSilentAsync instead. https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token